# Is HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback Size parameter calculated programmatically or by hardware

Tags: c++, c, embedded, stm32-hal

I'm realizing UART-DMA with STM_HAL library and I want to know if message size is counted by hardware (counting clock ticks till line is idle for example) or by some program method(something like strlen). So if `Size` in

```
HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint16_t Size)
```

is counted by hardware, I can send data in pure HEX format, but if it is calculated by something like `strline`, I may recieve problems if data is `0x00` and have to send data in ASCII.

I've tried to make some research in generated code in Keil but failed (maybe I didn't try hard enough) so maybe somebody can help me.

Comment: It's going to be the number of frames received.  What may vary is whether invalid frames (missing stop bit, wrong parity, etc) set the corresponding error flag and also store a byte, or set the error flag without storing any byte.  Transferring a binary zero byte will work just fine if it has the correct stop bit(s) (and if parity is enabled, the correct parity).  Sending a zero continuously with no stop bits over UART is interpreted by the receiver as the "BREAK" event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **UART DMA**, it is calculated by hardware.

If you check the call hierarchy of `HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback` using your ide, you can see how the Size variable is calculated.

The function is executed in the following flow.(Depending on the version of HAL Driver, it may be slightly different)

1. UART Idle Interrupt occur
2. Call `HAL_UART_IRQHandler()`
3. If DMA mod is enabled, Call `HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback(huart, (huart->RxXferSize - huart->RxXferCount))`

Therefore, `Size` variable is calculated as `(huart->RxXferSize - huart->RxXferCount)`

- `huart->RxXferSize` is a set value when initializing RX DMA.
- `huart->RxXferCount` is `(huart->hdmarx)->Instance->NDTR`

NDTR is a value ***calculated by hardware*** as the size of the buffer remaining after DMA transfer data to memory!!

Comment: So this is size of buffer I set up in `HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA` minus num of bits counted?

Comment: Yes. But it's a byte not a bit.

Comment: And "free space" is more correct than "bits counted". Check the DMA NDTR register description in datasheet.